# Http to https through apache avoiding CORS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I'm looking to make a proxy in apache to avoid CORS problems with an API I need to call from an Angular2 App.

Through a NodeJS+Express server I success with http-proxy-middleware, But it's impossible to reproduce it with Apache.

As I said, I need to make a request from angular via http to an API, which is on https and it;s external to my server.

I tried with ProxyPass and Rewrite, the most near I found is to make a redirect...but isn't useful for the angular2 App.

Here is my ProxyPass, I receive a 500 http error

```
ProxyPass /api https://url-to-external-api
ProxyPassReverse /api https://url-to-external-api
```

Here is my Rewrite and ProxyPass, I receive the response I want, but it makes a 302 http redirection and this is not possible to use inside an Angular2 App

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) https://url-to-external-api/$1 [R,N]
```

Any ideas to help?

Comment: We need more information about the issue, since what you ask certainly is possible, typically with the `ProxyPass` directive you posted. So the question is: what _exactly_ is the issue you ran into?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited to add more info

Comment: Sorry, can't spot any additional information... so again: what is the _exact_ issue you have? Any error you get? Which one? Anything in the http servers error log file? What?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the comment before edit the question.
With the proxypass I receive a 500, with rewrite I receive a 302, that is not useful on Angular2 App

Comment: An http status 500 is a servier internal issue, that is why I asked for the entries in the http servers error log file. That is where you can simply _read_ what the _exact_ issue is. Most likely the proxy module is not loaded...

Comment: Certainly I saw this errors repeated:

1 : HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for
2 : server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?
3 : server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Maybe 2 and 3 could be produced by bad certificates because it's a test server.

Comment: Ah, ok, there you have your answer: the proxy mechanism _does_ work, but_ the external API uses an invalid ssl certificate.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll continue my research through this point